# Checkout and merge a file from other branch in git

Tags: git-merge

I maintains two branches `master` and `pathogen` for my vim scripts. Both of them have their respective `vimrc` files. Now I want to merge both of them together and save it as `vimrc` of branch `pathogen`.

What I am doing now is checking-out vimrc from `master` branch and append it to the `vimrc` of pathogen. Is there a cooler way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git pull origin pathogen
```

Should do the trick